# What does the C syntax `Type varname[integer];` do when used with the + operator?

Tags: objective-c, c, types

I'm looking through [some low-level Objective-C code](https://github.com/macmade/EOSFTPServer/blob/master/EOSFTPServer/AsyncSocket/AsyncSocket.m#L456) and I see this:

```c
Byte seq[termLength];
```

<sup>(`termLength` is a `NSUInteger`, which is a `unsigned long` in my environment; `Byte` is a `UInt8`, which is a `unsigned char`)</sup>

I'm not as familiar with the C part of Objective-C... what does this do? To my eye it looks like it creates a new array of `Byte`s named `seq` that is `termLength` long without initializing the memory therein, but then later on I see this:

```
memcpy(seq + bufLen, pre, preLen);
```

I'm quite confused about this part. `bufLen` is a `NSUInteger`. How would one add a `NSUInteger` to a `Byte[]`? What would that even do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is a C array. You can read about C arrays here:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Arrays_and_strings

C arrays can be used like pointers, including pointer arithmetic. So, if you add `bufLen` to `seq`, what you end up with is a pointer to the position `bufLen` bytes into `seq`. So `(seq + buflen)[0]` gets you the same byte as `seq[bufLen]`, `(seq + buflen)[1]` gets you `seq[bufLen + 1]`, etc. Hopefully `bufLen` is less than `termLength`.

Comment: Okay, so second half of the question: what does `seq + bufLen` mean?

Comment: @BenLeggiero There you go.

Comment: It's effectively taking a subslice of the array, if that helps?

Comment: I'm getting conflicting info from CharlesSrstka and @zwol... Is it an item in a slot of an array, or is it a whole slice of the array?

Comment: It's a new pointer that begins somewhere in the middle of the array. Since pointers and arrays have similar syntax in C, you can indeed treat it like a subslice of the array.

Comment: I see! So `memcpy` is probably going to use it like an array, given how the writer used it, but this syntax is no different in behavior than `memcpy(seq[bufLen], pre, preLen)`?

Comment: @BenLeggiero Close. It would be the same behavior as `memcpy(&seq[bufLen], pre, preLen)`. Just `seq[bufLen]` would get you the char itself rather than a pointer to it. You need a pointer (or an array, which gets turned into a pointer by compiler magic), since that is what `memcpy` expects for its first argument.

Comment: Thanks, @CharlesSrstka! Sorry if I seem a bit ignorant but I was brought up in Java so all this pointer-play is foreign to me.

Comment: @BenLeggiero You get the hang of it after a while. And once you do, you'll start missing the explicit pointer syntax when you write in modern languages. For example; suppose you have an array. Then you create a new array variable and assign the first array to it. Then you modify the second array. Does the first array also get modified? Answer: Depends on the language. Swift: No. Java: Yes. You basically have to keep track of whether each type is a value type or reference type, _per language_, to know what'll happen. In C you just see if there's a `*`, and you know. Damn kids! Get off my lawn.